# Wordpress conditional within nested loop and ACF relationship lookup

Tags: wordpress, conditional-statements, nested-loops, advanced-custom-fields

I have WP_query finding products.

```
'<?php 
  $args = array(
  'post_type' => 'products',
  'posts_per_page' => -1 ,
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'orderby' => 'menu_order',      
  );
  $products = new WP_Query( $args );?>
  <?php if ( $products->have_posts() ) : ?>
          <!-- layout stuff -->
  <?php while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post(); ?>
          <!-- layout stuff -->'
```

Within the product loop, get_posts pulls in a list of CPT posts.

```
'<?php 
 $serviced_ids = get_field('serviced');
 $serviced = get_posts(array(
  'post_type' => 'services',
  'posts_per_page' => -1 
 ));
 ?>
 <?php if( $serviced ): ?>
    <!-- layout stuff -->
 <?php foreach( $serviced as $service ): ?>'
```

Next to each CPT post, it looks to see if the product exists in an ACF relationship. If so, it displays a Yes, else it displays a No.

```
'<?php 
  if( !empty($serviced_ids) && is_array($serviced_ids) && 
  in_array($serviced->ID, $serviced_ids) ): ?>
      Yes
  <?php else: ?>
      No
  <?php endif; ?>  '
```

So far so good ...

I then want to add a conditional element in the ELSE output if the CPT ID equals 50. I can not get this to work.

I've tried

```
'<?php else: ?>
   <?php if($products->ID = 50): ?>
     <?php echo $something; ?>
   <?php endif; ?>'
```

My fluency with PHP is not so great and can't get past this.

The output I'm looking for is:

PRODUCT NAME

- Service name: Yes
- Service name: Yes
- Service name: No
- Service name: $something else
- Service name: Yes

PRODUCT NAME

- Service name: No
- Service name: No
- Service name: No
- Service name: $something else
- Service name: No

Comment: Your current global $post object is set by $products->the_post().  If you want to know the post_id (or ID) of the current product, you want get_the_ID();

Comment: Documentation for global post object: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/$post

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Pendo for heading me in the right direction with get_the_ID(). The line of code I needed was:

```
'<?php if( get_the_ID() === 50) : ?>'
```